# Elliptic surface calculator

Tags: elliptic-curves

In kuwata's package : elliptic surface calculator 
i want to transform quartic to cubic with specific point but every time it say's : the point is not on the curve . can anybody tell me the correct command? maybe it have some problem . i asked this for the developer  with no answer.